# Are writing to snowflake table timeouts a concern for directly implementing the Node.JS Snowflake API into a mbile app?

Tags: node.js, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We are working on a mobile app that is written in Node.Js. We have error tracking, but we would like to be able to capture error responses in greater detail than we can with the current analytics implementation (which is using firebase, so it also limits our ability to extract the data).

The development team has concerns that pushing data from the phone app to snowflake risks causing performance issues on the app if for some reason snowflake's data warehouses are bogged down / slow to respond.

I don't think this is a concern, because the node.js implementation of the snowflake driver uses asynchronous calls. My understanding of this means that when the client would encounter an error and want to push data to snowflake, it would fork a separate thread while the rest of the app would be able to continue along it's normal execution process. Thus if the server was too unresponsive, the client would just queue up the data until it the server was ready to handle it or time out.  Am I wrong about this?

Secondly, we could do load testing on the snowflake data warehouse at different sized instances using sample data to determine the rate/volume where the server would become bogged down without autoscaling being invoked.

Am I wrong? Are there other things I'm not thinking about?

Thanks